# Grand total of calculated fields in a pivot table?

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

I have data like below, with a pivot table, and a calculated field.
 I'd like to see `1000` in *H7* instead of `900`.

[image: Screenshot]

---

***Rounded* is a calculated field** with formula `=ROUND(Income; -2)` for rounding to 100.

But the Grand Total for *Rounded* shows the sum for the original *Income* data (rounded afterward to `900`) instead of the sum of the calculated data above (that sums to `1000`).

**How to create a Grand Total for the calculated fields?**

I'm interested in a solution **preserving the Pivot Table references**. Currently, I'm already creating sum manually, but that just won't get updated automatically as data rows get added.

---

Raw data for recreating table:

```
Order;Client;Income
1;Bruce;120
2;Bruce;180
3;Clark;80
4;Peter;20
5;Peter;40
6;Clark;50
7;Clark;80
8;Peter;110
9;Bruce;50
10;Clark;160
```

Comment: Could you share source sample data with us , help to recreate  Pivot Table!

Comment: Thanks for getting back, I'll prepare a full sample table soon.

Comment: @RajeshS I updated the question with a full example. Would be great if you could help, or even help to rephrase the question perhaps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't have access to a version of Excel that features inserting calculated fields, but I can demonstrate what is happening in your case (which you correctly identified in the question).  I had to create another column with the rounded values, and then include that column in the pivot table:

[image]

You can see that the pivot table correctly summarizes the data when you do it this way (which is the solution to getting the result you want).  If you need a calculation applied to each raw value prior to aggregating, do it outside of the pivot table.

What is happening in your case is that Excel is aggregating the raw income values from your data table, then applying the rounding calculation to the aggregate.  So despite the column header label, the pivot table isn't performing the calculation you expect.  The column label in your pivot table would more accurately be "Rounded of Sum".

Pivot tables are a fantastic tool for simple aggregations, but you need to be careful about the sequence in which Excel applies calculations vs. aggregating, especially when you apply calculated fields or even use aggregation functions that involve more complex calculations than simple summing or counting.  For pivot tables with any complexity, it's a good practice to double check the results to confirm that it's doing what you want.

---

To preserve some of the discussion in the comment thread:

There are limitations to what you can do in a pivot table. If what you require is the aggregation shown in your example (aggregate, then round), you can't use a pivot table to spit out a total based on calculating it a different way. You would need to do that externally.  But that won't necessarily break everything every time the data changes (although you will need to trigger recalculation of the pivot table).

From the discussion, you have some complex requirements that benefit from the aggregation the pivot table offers, but don't lend themselves to doing it in a simple, straightforward way.  The best way to accomplish what you need may be combining calculations internal and external to the pivot table.

Add the Rounded calculation, like I did, as another data column that feeds the pivot table.  This is easy to maintain as you add or modify client records.  In the pivot table, keep your calculated rounding field since that displays the aggregations in the form you need.  Add another field that's the SUM of the new Rounded data column, as in my example. The pivot table will then contain everything calculated both ways, so everything you need is there.

Then you can deal with the appearance.  You can label the columns more descriptively, but if you don't want the new column visible, hide it.  You can stick a cell reference to its total under the visible portion of the pivot table, or even recreate your own Grand Total row and hide the one generated by the pivot table.

Comment: Thanks! I considered this solution, but for the grouped client aggregations I need the original sum first, then round it, then add up those aggregations. It is just how the country tax regulations go in my country.

Comment: E.g in the example above both Clark and Peter have a fake value reported, as their respective rounded aggregations show false values. I can work the issue around utilizing both solutions at once (both having the calculated field and the per transaction rounding), but that just blows up my production table (with monthly aggregations) to huge size.

Comment: Still, I'd like to some custom aggregations, perhaps some scripting magic or similar.

Comment: @Geri, there are limitations to what you can do in a pivot table.  If what you require is the aggregation shown in your example (aggregate, then round), you can't use a pivot table to spit out a total based on calculating it a different way.  You would need to do that externally and then display that result under the pivot table.

Comment: Thanks for taking your time anyway! I'll credit the bounty soon if no more answers come.

Comment: External calculations gets broken every time new records adds new columns to the resulting pivot table. It really defeats the purpose of using pivot tables, a.k.a. let the computer to the math automatically, instead of utilize error-prone human intervention on each data update.

Comment: The regulations are broken in the first place. It should tolerate errors on totals for rounded aggregations. But it does not.

Comment: @Geri, take a look at using tables and named ranges.  That may at least help with the problem of data update and expansion without breaking the pivot table, at least for rows (although you will need to trigger a recalculation).

Comment: Yap, it already uses named ranges, it is just the resulting grouped pivot table that changes row count each time a new client is added, so the range of the manual sum needs to be updated manually each time (for each month).

Comment: @Geri, what about just adding the Rounded calculation as another data column, and create the pivot table so it contains both the internally calculated column and the rounded data column.  The pivot table will then do all of the work of aggregation, data changes will include the calculated column, and you have both values in the pivot table.  Just apply good column labels so it's clear what each one is.  (cont'd)

Comment: If other people need to see the pivot table and you don't want to show the "conflicting" numbers, just hide the applicable portions.  You could even add a cell under the pivot table that references the desired pivot total based on the hidden data column.

Comment: @fixer1234,, nice one is working ☺ If possible upload the Animated Screen Shot !!

Comment: @fixer1234 Yep, basically I outlined the same workaround at https://superuser.com/questions/1419126/grand-total-of-calculated-fields-in-a-pivot-table/1419711#comment2143153_1419711

Comment: @fixer1234 Hiding is tricky, as I'd need values from one column, but Grand Total from the other.

Comment: @Geri, I deleted my example spreadsheet or I would just mock it up, but hiding should be trivial.  Take the example in my answer.  Imagine that my col E is your col H.  In row 6, you could recreate the Grand Total row.  Any pivot table total you want to retain, just use a cell reference to the cell above.  Now say you want the col E total to be 1000 instead of 890 (900 in your col H).  You stick `=F5` in E6.  Then you hide col F and hide row 5.  It will look exactly like what you describe.  To avoid hiding data rows, just stick the pivot table in a non-conflicting location, like another tab.

Comment: Alternative: don't hide the Grand total row, just add the value you want under the pivot table total.  So it could be a single value, just the `=f5` in E6.  Hiding col F won't affect the data.  You could add a label for it in D6.

Comment: Thanks, it could work **at the current state**. But as I add new data with a new client, it increases pivot table row count, that shifts grand total cell downwards, which breaks manual referencing. Also, a manual cell under the pivot table prevents it from updating, as it could not stretch downwards.

Comment: I think I'll just create an intermediate pivot table for grouping and rounding, without any grand total. Then use that table as the data source for the resulting pivot table with grand total. It could work automaticall without any manual tweak, and scales nicely with any data change.

Comment: @Geri, I had some more thoughts for you.  This comment thread is getting long, so I created a chat room and posted them there.  You can stop by at https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91817/discussion-between-geri-and-fixer1234.  Just FYI, the chat rooms work like comments in that you need to address posts to the other user with @ in order for them to get an alert to your post.